# Palindrome coding and logic

Tags: string, logic

When investigating if a string is Palindrome, cant i just take the reverse of the reversed string? whats wrong with my code?

```
def reverse(s):
    return s[::-1]

def isPalindrome(s):
    if (s == reverse(reverse(s))):
        return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reverse(reverse(s))` always equals `s`. You want to check whether `s` equals `reverse(s)`:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    return s == reverse(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are aiming to do. If you just want to have the logic implemented, then your version would work (yet you still have to correct your bug there, it's `if (s == reverse(s))` and not reversing the reversed version); however, if that's the task which was given to you in your coding interview, then you're not really doing it right, because of:

1. You're using an integral API call to reverse the string (and hence you're not implementing `isPalindrome`);
2. The time complexity of your version will be much worse than the
   complexity of `isPalindrome` algorithm per se.

Comment: Time complexity of optimal `isPalindrome` is still O(n) so the time complexity would stay the same assuming a reasonable implementation of `reverse()`.

Comment: @sevko I wouldn't say that it's still O(n). It's Θ, and O are both n/2, if implemented by a respective algorithm.

Comment: @LeeHongwei, consider the case you're having, as I've mentioned in the answer. The way your code is written, doesn't show the Algorithm implementation.. it's rather native API call, but the `isPalindrome` algorithm would always take n/2 in a good algorithm implementation. Also, IFF my answer helped you, you can upvote it, and if it answered your question, you may also accept it.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri O() is commonly used where people really mean Θ(), especially on SO. Moreover, Θ(n/2) = Θ(n). Constant factors don't matter.

Comment: @sevko not at all. By O, people never mean Θ, as for the most of algorithms, these two are entirely different measurements. You can Google for the complexities, for instance, sort algorithms. In the `isPalindrome` algorithm, you don't need to iterate over entire input 1 to n, but you're right, that runtime will accordingly increase as n increases.. however, it's not 1-1 relationship.